# Any performance implications of LVM and ZFS snapshots over time?

Tags: backup, vmware, lvm, zfs

Is it bad practice to take and keep LVM or ZFS snapshots over the long-term as backups or archives?

I agree snapshots are no substitute for making a second (or third) copy to take off-site, for example; however, are there any performance implications in LVM and ZFS from taking a snapshot and then keeping it around forever?

I recently came across the following statement about LVM snapshots:

> ...[Snapshots] do slow the system down.Snapshots only consume as much space as you give them.... (Think about how much will be written while the snapshot is live). Snapshots should be viewed as temporary resources while data is backed up or equivalent.

This attitude seems consistent with what's in the [LVM HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshots_backup.html): Create the snapshot, do the backup, delete the snapshot.

I learned the same thing during VMware's vSphere Install, Configure, and Manage training course. I can't recall the exact reason described in the course, but it probably has to do with performance implications of using delta disks. [This page](http://up2v.nl/2011/05/09/know-the-performance-impact-of-snapshots-used-for-backup/) seems to describe the situation well.

On the other hand, from the way I understand [how ZFS works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS#Snapshots_and_clones), snapshots seem like they could live forever without causing problems.

A gentleman even [describes](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2008/11/crontab-generated-zfs-snapshots.html) how to take hourly snapshots, and over time preserving one each day, one each week, etc.

Is there any problem with hanging onto ZFS snapshots this way?

Are LVM snapshots just as light-weight as ZFS snapshots, or do they work more like VMware's delta disks?

Comment: You might also want to look into thin provisioning on LVM. It also claims to have no performance overhead with snapshots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ZFS supposedly has no performance impact to keeping multiple snapshots around.  Conventional LVM snapshots however, do have terrible performance for keeping even one of them around for long, and it gets much worse with more snapshots.  A new snapshot system has been in the works for LVM for some time that that alleviates the worsening condition from keeping around multiple snapshots but it is not yet the default.

The typical means of working around this is to take a temporary snapshot, then back that up using conventional means such as `tar`, `rsnapshot`, or `dump`.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, a snapshot on ZFS is just another dataset with a special kind of deduplication. Since the number of datasets in a pool does not affect overall pool performance (except the disk space taken, obviously), I do not see a problem with keeping snapshots as long as there is sufficient space on the disk.

I have used snapshots extensively to share common data between virtual disk images of cloned VMs and did not notice any performance issues. They are not suitable backup strategy, of course, because they do not provide recovery from any disaster except user error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what version of ZFS others are using, but on Proxmox 5.4-6, with ZFS 0.7.13-pve1~bpo2, on spinning rust, keeping older ZFS snapshots long-term (~24 months) has a very significant impact on performance.

Copying a 250MB file from one folder to another, on the same drive, would fail to complete in 5+ minutes on a drive with 2 old snapshots. After the snapshots were removed, the copy would complete in ~1 minute.